# how to parse a protobuf3 message without knowing its type at compile time with golang?

Tags: go, reflection, protocol-buffers

here's a scenario:

you're implementing in golang a generic component that can may be used with any type of proto message (binary serialization) and need to deserialize binary proto data without knowing its type at compile time.

for instance, i encountered this issue while writing a generic kafka json archiver, the component would:

- receive a message type (string) from configuration and a name of a kafka topic
- would need to create the binary -> memory deserializer and the memory -> json serializer at runtime.

how do you get a deserializer for your binary bytes just from the message name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

golang proto libraries have a helper utility for this purpose:

```
// MessageType returns the message type (pointer to struct) for a named message.
// The type is not guaranteed to implement proto.Message if the name refers to a
// map entry.
func MessageType(name string) reflect.Type {
   // ....
}
```

to use it you can use a method similar to this:

```
func getProto(messageType string, messageBytes []byte) proto.Message {
    pbtype := proto.MessageType(messageType)
    msg := reflect.New(pbtype.Elem()).Interface().(proto.Message)
    proto.Unmarshal(messageBytes, msg)
    return msg
}
```

i have put a full example of this on github: 
https://github.com/rotemtam/pbreflect-example

Comment: I looked at your example. In your model file message.pb.go, which I assume is the generated file. I see two 'init' functions which register your type and register a file. The string the registerType call is the same as your messageType. That's not there in my generated code. Is there some option I need to pass to protoc when I build the .proto file?

Comment: @DnjAbc - nothing special, as you can see in https://github.com/rotemtam/pbreflect-example/blob/master/gen-proto.sh there are no special flags. the go team did blog about a new proto API, so you might be hitting that: https://blog.golang.org/protobuf-apiv2

Comment: proto.MessageType was DEPRECATED. Use: 

t, _ := protoregistry.GlobalTypes.FindMessageByName(protoreflect.FullName(str))
m := t.New().Interface()
proto.Unmarshal(bytes, m)